# Typescript compile error in promise.then

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm trying to use promises in typescript.  I used tsd to install es6-promise and added the reference to my file.  It understands promises for the most part, but I'm having difficulty chaining them with `then`.

```
function foo() : Promise<any> {
  var p: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();
  var x: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();
  p = p.then(x);
  return p;
}
```

gives me this at the location of `p.then(x)`:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any) => {} | Thenable<{}>'.

Is this somehow a bug in the [type definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts), or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> p.then(x);

This is invalid. `x` needs to be function. Here you have it as a promise.

Comment: That's it.  Strange, I thought this worked in vanilla js.  Leave it to typescript to show me all the wrong things I was doing!

Comment: @arolson101: Well, in vanilla js is doesn't throw a type error… but it doesn't "work" either. The argument is just ignored when it's not a function, and a promise equivalent to `p` is returned.

Comment: Wow, +1 typescript here for catching a very real bug.